# What is the right way return from fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have an activity that has a pop-up menu bar, where you can select a specific item that changes the activity screen to a fragment screen.
When the menu is closed and the back button is pressed,I want the screen changes to the screen of the same activity that was before the fragment screen appeared.

I tried these functions but:

1. First brought me back to the main screen of the program - the previous activity to activity that was replaced with the fragment screen.
2. The second did nothing.
3. The third one worked, but I'm not sure that's the right way to do it

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

       if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
           drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       } else {
           super.onBackPressed();
       }
   }

    @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

       if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
           drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       } else {
           getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

       if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
           drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       } else {
           startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: fragments do not replace activities, fragments are contained within activities. The activity should listen to the onBackPressed and remove the fragment from the stack instead of the fragment calling startActivity

Comment: How can I do that in this onBackPressed function?

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is, I believe, the correct method.

However, you still need to call `.beginTransaction()` and `.commit()`.

As mentioned by Tim Castelijns, it's your activity that should be listening for this.